# How to apply lazy quantifier in this given scenario?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to match an occurrence with the regex:

```
to(.*?) CITY[\d]
```

against

```
John from beautiful CITY1 in sdfsf to dsfs in sf to abc CITY2 to CITY3 for 3 days
```

I get two matches :

```
to dsfs in sf to abc CITY2 
to CITY3
```

My problem is that I want a regular exp using which I could get a match as "to abc CITY2" instead of "to dsfs in sf to abc CITY2".

I read about lazy quantifiers but couldn't apply it in this scenario.

Comment: I think you need to change the expression/logic to something like this [`to(?: \w+)? CITY\d`](http://regex101.com/r/aM5oU3/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\bto\b(?:(?!\bto\b).)*?CITY\d+
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iZ9sO5/7

Here we use negative lookahead to ensure the any character after `to` does not match `to`.So it will pick the nearest `to` to `City`.

`(?!\bto\b)` negaitve lookahead to not match to

`.)*` quantifying it

Comment: Thanks, It works. @HamZa has suggested a cleaner regex.